# Rollup output is hashed and contains exports

Tags: typescript, rollup

I have this chrome extension which uses a background script. This background script is written in typescript, and so far I was able to use `tsc` and then `browserify` to create a single file/bundle. This worked fine until I needed socker.io-client. With that `browerify` couldn't do the job anymore, so I looked for something else, and found Rollup.

I have something up and running now, but when I try to load the chrome extension it gives me an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

I would expected it to replace those as well (I guess) and inline all the dependencies.

So, here is my rollup.config.js file

```
import merge from 'deepmerge';
import { createBasicConfig } from '@open-wc/building-rollup';

const baseConfig = createBasicConfig();

export default merge(baseConfig, {
    input: './out-tsc/src/background/background.js',
    output: {
        dir: 'dist',
    }
});
```

And my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "outDir": "out-tsc",
    "rootDir": "./"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/background/background.ts",
    "./src/background/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

And the command I use to compile my background script is:

```
$> tsc --build ./tsconfig-background.json && rollup -c rollup.config.js
```

Any suggestion how I can resolve the `exports` error ?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a very basic Webpack example which does exactly what I needed. Although this is not the answer to my question, but is solves my issues and maybe it can help others as well. Here is the Webpack code:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/background/background.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "background.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" }]
    }
}
```